# Как правильно: по длине, в длину или длиной?

Tags: выбор-слов

***По длине*** они около двадцати сантиметров. Они около двадцати сантиметров **по длине.**

***В длину*** они около двадцати сантиметров. Они около двадцати сантиметров **в длину.**

***Длиной*** они около двадцати сантиметров. Они около двадцати сантиметров **длиной.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильны ***последние два*** предложения, причём в последнем я бы скорее поставил *"длиной"* в конец предложения, хотя можно и так.

Comment: *в последнем я бы скорее поставил "длиной" в конец предложения* — Вы хотели сказать "в предпоследнем"? Потому как в последнем оно и так в конце.

Comment: Поэтому теперь не совсем понятно, считаете ли Вы верными только третий пункт из трёх (два предложения) или второй и третий (четыре предложения).

Comment: @grizzly: посмотрите до редакции. Их было всего три.

Comment: Тогда согласен :)